# How can i change background color of footer in CSS

Tags: html, css

I create footer with footer tag `<footer>` , but my problem is I can't to change background color

Here is a code:

HTML:

```
<footer class="site-footer">

<div id="footer1"><p>Copyright  2013 Domain Name - All Rights Reserved </p></div>
<div id="footer2"><p> Template by OS Templates </p></div>

</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}


#footer1{
margin-left:2%;
float:left;

}
#footer2{
margin-right:2%;
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `site-footer` to an id instead of a class with some defined height. Fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uz9dkfy1/9/)

```
<footer id="site-footer">

<div id="footer1"><p>Copyright  2013 Domain Name - All Rights Reserved </p></div>
<div id="footer2"><p> Template by OS Templates </p></div>

</footer>

#site-footer {
height: 50px;
background: red;
}


#footer1{
margin-left:2%;
float:left;

}
#footer2{
margin-right:2%;
float:right;
}
```

Comment: In my case thats code not working, but i see on jsfidle working perfeclty.
Why?

Comment: Just make sure you change `class` to `id` and ensure everything else is the same. It should work.

Comment: I copy and paste your code, and doesn't work

Comment: Try adding `background: none;` to the footer1 and footer2 div styles.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 40.0.2214.9 ,and in Mozilla same situations.

Comment: Can you link the page to me please?

Comment: Here is http://jsfiddle.net/rg0umv3L/ 
my site is not responsive yet

Comment: Cool. Put this: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right before `<footer>` tag. Let me know if that works. It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/rg0umv3L/8/

Comment: thats it, thank you so much man! How can i  positive chech your help, i think you understand me my english is not very good

Comment: Click the checkmark beside my answer, haha. glad you got it working!

Comment: Why did you remove mine as the right answer? Jeez, I helped you out!

Comment: sorry man, i am begginer on this site,  i will now return right answer, i thinked can two check right answers. sorry again

Comment: I said put the clear:both style in as well, so give me some points too

Answer (score 0):

Your #footer1 and #footer2 divs are covering the .site-footer div, that's why you can't see the background color, try apply background transparency on this two divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing footer element to a div. Or using backgroun:inherit for #footer1 and #footer2

Comment: no it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Since #footer1 and #footer 2 both float .site-footer has no height.

Use a clear fix on .site-footer

hear is an example

```
.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: I don't understand you , and this code. Sorry about that

Comment: add the above class to your CSS then add 

the class clearfix to class="site-footer"

class="site-footer clearfix"

Comment: just search for clearfix and maybe you will understand it.  It's an important concept.

Answer (score 0):

Add another div in after the footer divs, with style="clear:all".

Comment: not working, i make another div after footer2, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, got it working for you

```
background:inherit;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lz53cad/1/

If you don't want white space between the elements use padding instead of margin.

Just as I said. Please mark my answer as the right answer.