# How do I change the footer background color in css?

Tags: css, footer

I am having trouble changing the footer background colour in my CSS doc.

```
footer{ background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; }
```

I also can't change the aside background color.

```
aside{ background-color: lightgray; }
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i change background color of footer in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245492/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-footer-in-css)

Comment: any other code you can provide? html maybe? popping it on jsfiddle is always a good choice

Answer (score 3):

You can use a div inside the footer. See bellow fiddle:

```css
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}

#footer-content {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div id="footer-content">
    <p>Copyright 2017 @ Domain - All Rights Reserved </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is work for FREE THEMES specifically.

```
.site-footer .footer-top {

    background: #eee    ;
}
```

If you want to change the background color of footer text area as well, you can add following code with the first one ine the customize>Additionial CSS are:

```
.site-footer .footer-bottom {

    border-top: 1px solid #eee;

    background: #eee ;

}
```

Hope this will work for everyone, specially those who are using any free wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
    background-color: #40e0d0;
    text-align: justify;
} 
aside {
    background-color: ;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Above script is perfect working on my blogger site on "Add custom CSS editing theme code"
https://www.seemainfoelibrary.com/search/label/Business%20Law

Thank you ever much I was searching such type of script.